# How do I avoid to launch systemd user units on non-graphical user sessions?

Tags: linux, xorg, systemd

I am currently deploying systemd user units which should be launched every time a user logins in. However, the service spawns an application that depends on the environment variable $DISPLAY. Therefore, I would like to know if there is any mechanism that prevents the unit to launch on non-graphical user sessions, such as: local tty sessions and remote sessions through ssh.

**Edit #1: You can find the Unit file bellow for the service.**

```
[Unit]
Description= User session Unit

[Service]
Type=forking
Restart=always
RestartSec=1
ExecStart=/usr/share/App/exec.sh start $HOME
ExecStop=/usr/share/App/exec.sh stop $HOME
ExecReload=/usr/share/App/exec.sh reload $HOME

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```